# Is there a way to use values in a list to search a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of list that has values which are the same as some keys in a dictionary, like so:

```
list_a = [["a", "c", "e"], ["b", "f", "g"], ["b", "d", "i"]]
dict_a = {"a": "3", "b": "3", "c": "2", "d": "5", "e": "4", "f": "3", "g": "3", "h": "1", "i": "1"}
```

I want to use the values in list_a to access dict_a and check if the values by those keys are the same. To make myself clear: I take the first list in list_a and use those values to check if values in dict_a by keys "a", "c" and "e" share the same value. If yes (so if those three keys share the same values) do something, if not keep looking. So far I have tried different variations of this:

```
for i in range(len(list_a)):
check = list_a[i]
  for j in range(len(check)):
      if dict_a[check[j]] == "3":
        #do stuff
```

With no result other than doing the thing every time it find a correspondence. What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:`

Comment: The second loop needs to be indented inside the first loop.

Comment: `for check in list_a:` `for j in check:` `if dict_a[j] ...:`

Comment: does list_a always contain  a list of 3 elements ? If yes then can be done in one loop.

Comment: `if any(( (w:=dict_a[x]) ==(q:=dict_a[y])==(r:=dict_a[z])) for x,y,z in list_a)` Simply using any and walrus operator you can do this

Answer (score 2):

Use the `all()` function to check if all the values are the same.

And use `any()` to test if this is true for any of the sublists in `list_a`.

```
if any((all(dict_a.get(v) == dict_a.get(check[0]) for v in check) for check in list_a):
    # do stuff
```

Comment: You might want to use `dict_a.get(v, v)`. It might be an error in the question, but the dictionary doesn't have an entry for the key `'i'`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Although this makes things better, it still does the stuff after the "if" more than one time. I want it to do it only once, not for every correspondence.

Comment: Then add a `break` to leave the `for` loop.

Comment: @XiSocGame I've updated the answer to use `any()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the first matching result you can get it in one line of code:

```
list_a = [['a', 'c', 'e'], ['b', 'f', 'g'], ['b', 'd', 'i']]
dict_a = {'a': '3', 'b': '3', 'c': '2', 'd': '5', 'e': '4', 'f': '3', 'g': '3', 'h': '1',
          '1': '1'}
if (result := next((sublist for sublist in list_a if len(set(dict_a.get(v, v) for v in sublist)) == 1), None)):
    # do stuff
    print(result)
```

The basic idea is to loop over all inner lists. Then we take each element of the inner list, get the corresponding value from the dictionary and build a set with all those values. If this set has only one element then all the values are the same. We return the element with `next` and provide a default value of `None` if no matching inner list could be found.

---

After your clarification that all those values must match a given value there is a different solution:

```
value_to_find = '3'
for sublist in list_a:
    if all(dict_a.get(value, value) == value_to_find for value in sublist):
        print(sublist)
        # your code here
        break
```

Remove the `break` if you want to perform the action on multiple inner lists if multiple inner lists match.

Comment: This seems to work, also when it shouldn't. I need it to do stuff when the keys defined in the list have a set value (for example, 3)

Comment: @XiSocGame I added a different code for this use case. The code in your question went into the right direction but you missed the `all` part. And of course using an index to loop over a list is a big no-no in Python and is called _unpythonic_.

Answer (score -1):

```
list_a = [["a", "c", "e"], ["b", "f", "g"], ["b", "d", "i"]]
dict_a = {"a": "3", "b": "3", "c": "2", "d": "5", "e": "4", "f": "3", "g": "3", "h": "1", "i": "1"}
for i in range(len(list_a)):
    check = list_a[i]
    lst = [dict_a[check[j]] for j in range(len(check))]
    if lst[:-1] == lst[1:]:
        print("All same")
    else:
        print("Not All same")
```